# Android 11 Storage Access and Java File Library

Tags: java, android, file

I have an android application already available on playstore. It is a file transfer app between PC to Android using localhost. I'm using following java function within it:

To create directory/file/show list of files and many other file functions(append, byte read/write etc):

```
file.mkdir
directory.listFiles();
file.createNewFile()
```

I had also put

```
 requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

And it is working fine on android 10 after giving sufficient read/write external storage permission.

But the problem is that these will not work on android 11 as requestLegacyExternalStorage will not work. I have used MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and the app works perfect but the problem is that playstore is not allowing it. (Don't know why they rejected the update)

I have also used getExternalFilesDir and it works perfect but don't like data to be in android folder and remove if app is deleted.

I have also tried to use download location and it works but the problem is getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"FileChat");
```

So what I wanted to ask how can I manage/use file library for android 11 to read/write/create/delete files and directory. It should not be in android folder as this will be deleted after app is deleted. Can I used public directory like downloads? If I can, what is the alternative to getExternalStorageDirectory()?

I don't need to read user data. Just want to have a directory in which app can store files. The read function is working as file is picked by user using intent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a new folder using `MediaStore` API. You don't need `requestLegacyExternalStorage` as it is not going to work from A11 onwards. I would suggest you read about Scoped Storage once

Comment: Yes i know. But there are other functions needs to handle as well like bytes appending to file. So don't want to change code too much. Also i guess mediastore is limited to media files.

Comment: A file transfer app? For the files of the app or for files of other apps too? Quite a difference.

Comment: `but the problem is getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated:` Yes. But what does it matter? It works. On Android 11. And on Android 12 too. If you would acquire MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE than you would use it certainly. So it is there to use.

Comment: `used getExternalFilesDir and it works perfect` Yes but only for app's own files. My question is again: transfer for files of other apps too?

Comment: `but don't like data to be in android folder and remove if app is deleted.`  Not if you add a flag in manifest upon which the user will be asked to keep the files at uninstall.

Comment: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"FileChat");` Not nice. Better: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"FileChat");`

Comment: It transfer file from android to pc and receive files from pc to android. To transfer file from app to PC there is know issue as I get URI using Intent. But for receiving file from PC to android there is problem. Because it needs to create folder, create file, append file byte by byte. File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"FileChat"); This works perfect I know and don't even need permission on android 11. But problem is, it is depracated. If it is not a problem then I will use that.

Answer (score 1):

Top-level directory write access of shared storage is not available in Android 11, however you can use the existing File APIs to access the media and download collection folders like `/Pictures`, `/Downloads`, `/DICM` etc. It won't be possible to create your app's own folder as top level directory but it is possible to create a dedicated sub-directory in the default collection folders.

To keep your app running as expected on Android 10, `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag will also be required since access to shared storage on Android 10 was restricted via MediaStore APIs only.

Answer (score 1):

If transfer is only for your apps own files then put them in

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"FileChat");
```

Or use Storage Access Framework to let the user choose and or create a directory on external storage inclusive removable micro sd card.